# How to redirect back to original Url after OAuth login in Micronaut

Tags: security, oauth-2.0, micronaut

I'm writing a webapp using micronaut which uses oauth2 to secure the apis. its working well in the sense that the login page from the oauth provider is shown when a secured url is accessed. But after login the page doesn't redirect back to the original requested url, instead it goes bat to '/'. I believe this is because micronaut uses "micronaut.security.session.login-success-target-url" property find the url to go to after login. Since there are multiple secured urls I'd like to auto redirect to the original url if available.

Any help to achieve the same would be appreciated.

Please find below the properties:

```
---
micronaut:
  security:
    enabled: true
    token:
      propogation:
        enabled: true
    intercept-url-map:
      -
        pattern: /
        http-method: GET
        access:
          - isAnonymous() 
      -
        pattern: /oauth/**
        http-method: GET
        access:
          - isAnonymous() 
      -
        pattern: /**/login
        access:
          - isAnonymous() 
    endpoints:
      login:
        enabled: false
      logout:
        enabled: true
    session:
      enabled: true
      login-failure-target-url: /oauth/login/cognito 
      unauthorized-target-url: /oauth/login/cognito 
      forbidden-target-url: /oauth/login/cognito
    oauth2:
      enabled: true
      state:
        persistence: session
      clients:
        cognito: 
          client-secret: '${OAUTH_CLIENT_SECRET}' 
          client-id: '${OAUTH_CLIENT_ID}' 
          openid:
            issuer: 'https://cognito-idp.${COGNITO_REGION}.amazonaws.com/${COGNITO_POOL_ID}/'
            authorization:
              display: 'POPUP'
              prompt: 'CONSENT'
    token:
      jwt:
        enabled: true
        signatures:
          secret:
            generator:
              secret: '${JWT_GENERATOR_SIGNATURE_SECRET:pleaseChangeThisSecretForANewOne}'
    endpoints:
      oauth:
        enabled: true
      logout:
         enabled: true
         get-allowed: true
```

Comment: did you find solution? I faced same issue

Comment: there a property micronaut.security.redirect.prior-to-login which regulates this. See https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-security/latest/guide/#io.micronaut.security.config.RedirectConfigurationProperties